# Entegrating existing .mfile to the .mdl simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, robotics

I convert my .m file above as a function like below ,  my input is nothing and my output is q. But I have a problem. When I put my created function block to the simulink and connect to the display screen , matlab gives me some errors like;

***Try and catch are not supported for code generation.
Function 'tb_optparse.m' (#80.5667.6083), line 157, column 25:
"try"
Launch diagnostic report.***

***Function call failed.
Function 'MATLAB Function' (#94.848.897), line 37, column 3:
"mstraj(path, [15 15 15], [], [1 0 1], 0.02 , 0.2)"
Launch diagnostic report.***

**Errors occurred during parsing of MATLAB function 'MATLAB Function'(#93)**

How can I fix these errors? Thanks

```
function output = fcn()


%mdl_puma560    %to create puma robot

for type=1:3  % main for loop. It turns 3 times. At first, it sets the path
    %           to x-y plane and draw the robot, at second for y-z plane
    %           and then for x-z plane

  if type==1 

% The path of robot for x-y plane    
path=[0 0 1;0 0 0;0 2 0 ;0.5 1 0 ;1 2 0;1 0 0;1.5 0 1;1.5 0 0;
      1.5 2 0;2.2 2 0;2.5 1.6 0;2.5 0.4 0;2.2 0 0;1.5 0 0;0 0 1];


 elseif type==2   

% Same thing as first part    
path=[-0.5 0 0;0 0 0;0 0 1;0 -0.5 0.5;0 -1 1;0 -1 0;-0.5 -1.2 0;0 -1.2 0;
    0 -1.2 1;0 -1.7 1;0 -2 0.7;0 -2 0.3;0 -1.7 0;0 -1.2 0];


 elseif type==3

 % Same thing as first and second part     
path=[0 -0.5 0;0 0 0;0 0 1;0.5 0 0.5;1 0 1;1 0 0;1.3 -0.5 0;1.3 0 0;
    1.3 0 1;1.7 0 1;2 0 0.7;2 0 0.3;1.7 0 0;1.3 0 0];


  end



% I created a trajectory

p=mstraj(path, [15 15 15], [], [1 0 1], 0.02 , 0.2);

% [15 15 15] means the maximum speed in x,y,z directions.
% [1 0 1] means the initial coordinates
% 0.02 means acceleration time
% 0.2 means smoothness of robot


numrows(p)*0.2;    % 200 ms sample interval
Tp=transl(0.1*p);  % Scale factor of robot
Tp=homtrans( transl(0.4,0,0),Tp);  % Origin of the letter
q=p560.ikine6s(Tp) ;  % The inverse kinematic


% for i=1:length(q)
% %q matrix has 280 rows and 6 columns. So this for loop turns 280 times
% % At every turns , it plots one part of movement. q(1,:), q(2,:), ...  
% 
%     p560.plot(q(i,:))
% 
% end

end

output=q;
```

Answer (score 0):

Well as the error message says, it looks like your function `mstraj` is calling `try/catch` which isn't supported for code generation (MATLAB functions in Simulink are first converted to C code when you run the model).

Have a look at [Call MATLAB Functions](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/simulink/ug/calling-matlab-functions.html) in the documentation for ways to work around this using `coder.extrinsic`. Extrinsic functions return data of type `mxArray` so you will need to convert it to whatever the data type of `p` (see **Converting mxArrays to Known Types** in the documentation page above).

In you case, it would probably look something like:

```
function output = fcn()

coder.extrinsic('mstraj');

% etc...

p = 0; % Define p as a scalar of type double (change to required data type if not appropriate)
p=mstraj(path, [15 15 15], [], [1 0 1], 0.02 , 0.2);

% etc...
```